# Redirect to referrer page after modal submission in Django

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

In my Django app, I have a couple of pages to

1. Create poll question `/poll/create-question`
2. Edit poll question `/poll/edit-question/<question_number>`

Each of those pages has an option to associate the question with a category name from a drop down list. The user can also create a category on the fly, if the required category is not present in the list.

On clicking a button to create the category, a Bootstrap modal pops up and the user can input the category name and submit it. This POST request is handled by a separate `view` function (with urlpattern `/poll/create-category`). Also, the create category option is available in both the pages (Create & Edit)

Things are working fine. Except that I wanted to redirect to the original page (i.e., Create or Edit) after the modal is closed. The request object has a property call `HTTP_REFERER` which holds the complete url `http://servername:port/poll/create-question`. But I wanted just the urlpattern of the referrer page `/poll/create-question`.

Is there a way in Django to get that and redirect to the original page upon submitting a modal? How is this kind of feature usually handled in Django?

Comment: You could store the current context (`'create'` or `'edit'`) in the session or append it as a query string to the `formaction` of the form that is submitted in the POST.

Answer (score 0):

I would say using the http referrer is not reliable. You should use class based views. Make two views that look like this. You can put all your logic in the first view and just override the success url method in the second view.

```
class CrateCategory (CreateView):
     model = Category

     def get_success_url (self):
         return '/poll/create-question/'

class CreateCategoryToUpdate(CreateCategory):

     def get_success_url (self):
          return '/poll/update-question/'
```

You should replace the urls with the reverse() method using url names.